# SWT - Can i custom draw the background of a Text control?

Tags: java, swt, paint

... I want to draw some info icon in the background of a text control.

I know about the paint event, but believe, if I do this, the entered text lies behind my custom drawn icon, not above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the text again.  Just calculate its X and Y and use `gc.drawText` to write it over the original text.